# using alias to send certain URL to different php directory

Tags: nginx

I am currently sending all request with '.php' to the php engine using the following:

```
root /var/www/public;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

I would like to get all requests to /login/... to be sent to a different directory on the php server. I gather that alias and try_files don't work together. I have tried using another 'root', but it doesn't work:

```
location ^~ /login/ {
    root /var/www/login/etc/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /login$is_args$args;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
}
```

How can I get this to work so all /login/... requests end up being served from /var/www/login/etc directory on php. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
http {
   ...
   map $request_uri $rot{
      "~ /login"  /var/www/login/etc/;
      default <insert_default_root>;
   }

   server {
      ...
      root $rot;
      ...
      location / {...}
      location ~ \.php$ {...}
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```